# How to downgrade flutter from version 2.5.3 to 1.22.6

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some older projects built on flutter 1.22.6 and now I am working on latest version of flutter but there often comes need when I've to work on previous projects non null safety one's so when I try to downgrade flutter by giving command `flutter downgrade 1.22.6` it tells me to downgrade to 2.5.2 and if I try to switch channel and then downgrade it downgrades to 2.5.2 first and then tells there is no version related to 1.22.6. This method used to be working before but now its not working anymore. I don't want to download zip files and then replace again flutter every-time I just want it to be done by cli.
My OS is windows 11

Comment: Instead of downgrading flutter, upgrade your projects, null safety is really nice to have, and you're also missing out on a lot of new features. Just saying

Comment: I have planned to do so but currently those apps are live and I've to do some bug fixing or minor additions so that's why. Whenever I'll get spare time I'll surely upgrade them to null safety

Comment: Does the old `git checkout v1.22.6` command (instead of the new `flutter downgrade 1.22.6` one) in the flutter install directory work? You must install flutter from the [git repo](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#downloading-straight-from-github-instead-of-using-an-archive) (git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
) to make the old command works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flutter Version Manager fvm its specifically made to control flutter versions plus along with that you can install flutter sidekick as well. I am attaching link for you.
[FVM](https://fvm.app/) [Flutter Sidekick](https://github.com/leoafarias/sidekick)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can no longer downgrade flutter versions, I have found the best way to do this is:

1. Download desired flutter version
2. Locate current 'flutter' folder and replace it with the desired version

if you run --flutter version after, it should show the correct version